# Image map in joomla

Tags: joomla, imagemap

I need to put an image map in a article. I'm using Joomla 1.6. I tried to disable the editor and insert plan HTML, but the following error is occuring:

> "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of
>   134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 51484653 bytes) in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\libraries\joomla\filter\filterinput.php
>   on line 358"

I also tried to disable "HTML filtering" in Article Manager, but the same error is still happening. I'm editing as super user.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your image map here?

I had problems using image maps in the past. Have you tried disabling the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Strange. I have an image map on http://www.affinitytrust.org/contact-us which works perfectly. This is just in the article content. Can you post your code please?